# callback function after css() jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function after `css()` jquery. I want something like this :

```
$("p").css({"color":"red"}).function({
     $("div").hide();
});
```

Comment: `.css()` is synchronous...

Comment: what are you really trying to do

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy did you mean that is impossible ??

Comment: Its hard to answer without knowing your exact requirement, your code and this `$("p").css({"color":"red"});   $("div").hide();` are pretty much same.. But i don't think `.css()` have a callback.

Comment: I check this answer and that work.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29792910/3106610

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `queue()` function:

```
$("p").css({"color":"red"}).queue(function() {
   $("div").hide();
   $(this).dequeue();
});
```